# Credential storage failed in eclipse in Mac OSX

Tags: eclipse, macos, tfs, azure-devops

When i'm connecting to server projects in tfs using eclipse in mac with my credentials it is connecting without any issues, but when i check the 'save password' at the login dialogue box it is showing an error as

**'Credential storage failed (Could not save your credentials)'**

Is there any way to get rid of this, because I don't want to enter my username and password every time when I open eclipse.

See the following images.

[image]

.

.

[image]

*Any comments or suggestions would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.*

Comment: There may be a more detailed message in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory.

Comment: @greg-449...I can't find any information regarding credentials saving error in that .log file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Keychain Access utility to fix it. If you see more than one tfs line in there remove the extras.
Click on the one you leave in the list.
I am foggy on details of what I did but I remember clicking on Access Control tab to allow keychain.
I think it needs your Mac account password to allow the keychain (not your TFS password).

Answer (score 4):

Andrei is correct. But, I thought it would help to clarify the steps:

- Start Keychain Access
- Click 'All Items' under 'Category'
- Enter the name of your tfs server into the search box
- Delete any entries whose 'name' is the same as your tfs server
- Try to connect again.

This worked for me. I had this problem after my password had changed.

Answer (score 0):

I occasionally run into this myself. I have not identified when it happens but I do suspect it has something to do with Eclipse updating itself, which ruins the signature. There is a [long standing open bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=391455) but I don't see it being addressed anytime soon.

Here is what I do to get it working again:
0. Close Eclipse

1. Open macOS Keychain
2. Search for password entry labeled "equinox.secure.storage"
3. Delete entry "equinox.secure.storage"
4. Open terminal
5. rm -rf ~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.equinox.security
6. Start Eclipse

(see [comment 40 on that bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=391455#c40))