# Eclipse doesn't save my passwords in Keychain Access

Tags: eclipse, macos, keychain

I have the same problem as this question [Credential storage failed in eclipse in Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323003/credential-storage-failed-in-eclipse-in-mac-osx/20651933) but the solutions suggested there doesn't work.

I read somewhere else about the process for adding passwords to MacOS's keychain from Eclipse:

Preferences → General → Security → Secure Storage → Change Password

To start with, it is weird that you *change password* when you set it up for the first time and there isn't a password.

So after a warning about current passwords might be inaccessible after a change I get this dialog

[image]

What?? I haven't even entered a password at this stage, so how can I create password hint?

After that I see this:

[image]

Changed to what??

And that is it. The next time I connect to Bitbucket I am asked for my password, and after that I don't need to enter a password - until I restart Eclipse, when it all start over and I have to perform these steps again and again enter the password to Bitbucket.

This happens on both my computers (one running Big Sur, one running Catalina). I have tried with Eclipse 2020-09 and 2020-12, with the same result.

It almost feels like a known bug but it feels unlikely

Comment: Which EGit version do you have? It should be fixed in EGit 5.10: https://git.eclipse.org/c/egit/egit.git/commit/?id=05f6aa2f360c8111b7b83af7dd824eb5b5eed531

Comment: Hmm, _Git Integration for Eclipse 5.9_?

Comment: EGit/JGit update site: [`https://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates`](https://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Credential storage failed in eclipse in Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323003/credential-storage-failed-in-eclipse-in-mac-osx)